# Date is wrongly converted when imported into RStudio from Oracle

Tags: r, date, locale, roracle

I'm working with an Oracle database and have a connection in RStudio using the `ROracle` package. For some reason some dates are converted when imported into R through either `dplyr` or `dbGetQuery`.

A date field that in the database reads `2018-01-01`, turns into `2018-01-31 23:00:00` when imported. The same is the case with `2018-02-01` that is converted to `2018-02-28 23:00:00`.

What is really weird is that if I export the data frame to an excel spread sheet using `openxlsx` the dates are again displayed correctly.

Anybody who knows what is going on, or could point me in the right direction? The column is formatted as `POSIXct`, and I´ve tried changing locale and timezone. I´ve also tried converting the date column with `as.Date`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with how ROracle converts dates when importing. The dates for the winter months where imported as CET while the rest of the dates where imported as CEST.

Found the explanation here: https://www.oralytics.com/2015/05/r-roracle-and-oracle-date-formats_27.html